# Get NullPointerException when call pack() JPOS

Tags: java, xml, iso8583, jpos

i worked in ISO 8583. And i use JPOS to parse and unparse ISO message.
But, when i parse the message, i get this following error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.pack(ISOBasePackager.java:94)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.pack(ISOMsg.java:442)
    at com.sti.payment.postpaid.service.TransactionService.response(TransactionService.java:76)
    at com.sti.payment.postpaid.App.main(App.java:35)
```

The error point to :

```
byte [] bIsoMsg = isoMsg.pack();
```

Here is my code :

```
public void response(String responseMessage) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager("de-payment-request.xml");

    // Buat ISO Messagenya
    ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
    isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
    isoMsg.setMTI("0210");
    isoMsg.set(1, "723A40010A818000");
    isoMsg.set(2, "162333444455556666");
    isoMsg.set(3, "380099");

    byte [] bIsoMsg = isoMsg.pack();
}
```

And here is my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE isopackager SYSTEM "genericpackager.dtd">
<isopackager>
  <isofield
    id="1"
    length="64"
    name="BIT MAP"
    class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BITMAP"
  />
  <isofield
    id="2"
    length="16"
    name="PRIMARY ACCOUNT NUMBER"
    class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"
  />
  <isofield
    id="3"
    length="6"
    name="PROCESSING CODE"
    class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"
  />
</isopackager>
```

What i missed?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Answer**
>
> For now may be it is not the best and fit answer for my problem. Just exclude the ID 1 in your pack method. It works for me. Cause JPOS automatically add ID 1 and 2 for your message.

Comment: BTW, I think you didn't configured field 0 (MTI). That's probably one of your problems.

Comment: where is i have to configure? XML?

Comment: In your `de-payment-request.xml`, the MTI would be field 0, in your case, probably configured as `IF_CHAR, length=4`

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Now it works, when i remove line where i set to ID 1. Cause JPOS automatically add the BITMAP to my packed message. ^^

Answer (score 1):

The bitmap field (data element 1) is handled automatically by jPOS, so you don't have to call:

`isoMsg.set(1, "723A40010A818000");`

When you set field 1, jPOS believes there are fields that are actually not configured and that's why you get an NPE, most likely [here](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/main/java/org/jpos/iso/ISOBasePackager.java#L94) (depending on your version).

Comment: My message actually as a response. I remove that line but still NullPointer

Comment: You sure field 1 has to be defined as IFA_BITMAP ? Please try `IFB_BITMAP`, it may solve your problem.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. It works now. I downgrade my version to 1.9.8